# Geonames api loop and get city name

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, geonames

```
$jsonfile = file_get_contents("http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?username=ksuhiyp&country=pt&maxRows=1000&style=SHORT");
    $jsondata = json_encode($jsonfile);
    $cities = explode(',', $jsondata);
    foreach($cities as $key => $value){
        echo $value;
    }
```

How can i get only all city names (eg... Lisbon, Porto, Aveiro...) contained in the array?

Here is a sample of the array:

```
{"totalResultsCount":37305,"geonames":[{"lng":"-9.13333","geonameId":2267057,"countryCode":"PT","name":"Lisbon","toponymName":"Lisbon","lat":"38.71667","fcl":"P","fcode":"PPLC"},{"lng":"-8.61099","geonameId":2735943,"countryCode":"PT","name":"Porto","toponymName":"Porto","lat":"41.14961","fcl":"P","fcode":"PPLA"},{"lng":"-8.42005","geonameId":2742032,"countryCode":"PT","name":"Braga","toponymName":"Braga","lat":"41.55032","fcl":"P","fcode":"PPLA"},{"lng":"-8.8882","geonameId":2262963,"countryCode":"PT","name":"Setúbal","toponymName":"Setúbal","lat":"38.5244","fcl":"P","fcode":"PPLA"},{"lng":"-8.13057","geonameId":2264397,"countryCode":"PT","name":"Portugal","toponymName":"Portuguese Republic","lat":"39.6945","fcl":"A","fcode":"PCLI"},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, that is a pretty ugly way to get at the data, as you are encoding json data that is already json, and then looping on just pieces of that resulting mangled string.

This will get you a resulting array of just names:

```
$jsonfile = file_get_contents("http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?username=ksuhiyp&country=pt&maxRows=1000&style=SHORT");
$geodat = json_decode($jsonfile,true);
$names = array();
foreach($geodat['geonames'] as $geoname) {
    $names[] = $geoname['name'];
}
print_r($names);
```

Example output:

```
Array (
    [0] => Lisbon
    [1] => Porto
    [2] => Braga
    [3] => Setúbal
    [4] => Portugal
    [5] => Coimbra
    [6] => Funchal
    [7] => Amadora
    [8] => Queluz
    [9] => Lisbon metropolitan area
    ...
```

Comment: `$names = array_column($geodat['geonames'], 'name');` would avoid that loop

Comment: @LawrenceCherone good point. I'm so used to doing OTHER things during a loop of data (tally something, grouping, etc)... that I always pour stuff into a `foreach` (bad habit for simple things).

Comment: Thank you. I was misreading the file contents information and thats way i was exploding it to convert in an array,

Comment: @AndréCastro the joys of `json_decode` ... it does all the fun frills for you :)